# Some servlet/jetty questions

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

Having the ServletAPI plus the configurations you can make to jetty or any other web container

1. Do we have a way to limit the request sizes ? (ie to close the connection if posting more that 50 MB)
2. Can we in some way kill the dispatching of a request that is taking too long ?
3. While dispatching a request in your own configured servlet, can we forward ( not redirect ) the request to the 'default' servlet. ? Will this allways work ?

   ```
   RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default");
   HttpServletRequest wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
     public String getServletPath() { return ""; }
   }; 
   rd.forward(wrapped, resp);
   ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Spring has something to take care of this. If you're using Spring, you're in luck, or else you need to roll your own solution based on what Spring does. I can't speak for other frameworks, but I guess many other frameworks would have some support for this.

Take a look at `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` and `org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException`

The `CommonsMultipartResolver` has a property `maxUploadSize` that lets you control the max size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414795/how-to-specify-http-request-timeout-parameter-on-java-servlet-container may have somthing of interest for you. However I'm not aware of anything in the servlet api that lets you cancel a request.