# Tomcat configure maxThreads per webapp

Tags: tomcat, configuration

is it possible to configure tomcat to use a predefined number of threads per webapplication?
The idear behind this is, if i deploy several applications on tomcat and let's assume one of those has a bug which results into a deadlock.

What happens is that this application will cause tomcat to create new threads until it reaches the maxThreads setting. After that no more Threads can be created which affects the other applications as well. It would be nice to tell tomcat something like "hey you can only serve 50 threads per application". If then the application with the deadlock reaches it's 50 Threads it will just be blocked, but the other applications will stay save.

thx,

kuku

Answer (score 1):

Maybe StuckThreadDetectionValve https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484800/1349691 helps in your case.