# Servlet does not respond

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a web application with differents servlets which are load on startup, after a while without making request with the application(I'm running inside Eclipse IDE and in linux red hat), when I do a new post request I see how it runs the doPost method but nothing more. I have a log just when it enters the method. Should I have to configure something in the tomcat or maybe in Eclipse to support long timeouts without interactions? It seems weird that accept the post request but nothing else.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

What I mean is I have some servlets which are running into a tomcat server and when I do some request to them, everything works perfect but imagine that I stop for a long time(20 minutes or more) making queries, the servlet does not respond. For figure out what happen, I put some logging in my post method and I see that it enters in the doPost method but then any command is executed. I understand that if before everything was working, it's not a problem about my coding and I was thinking that maybe there is some timeout that killed something in my applicacion(I'm new in servlets development) or maybe I have to set up something. Do you see my point?

Comment: please edit your question its very tough to understand whats your actual problem

Comment: Am sure your servlet will not be removed from the container though it does not have any access for a long time,try putting sop instead of logger and check

Answer (score 0):

"A post request comes in the `doPost` method, that takes very long. I see no response in the browser." Right?

A doPost should not take that long. If you show code, someone might have ideas to make it faster.

An answer on [timeouts in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout).

For testing what is going on, try inserting a bit of output.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=Windows-1252"); // Or so, for raw text
response.setHeader("Keep-Alive", "true";

for (;;) {
    ...
    out.print(".");
    out.flush();
```