# How to avoid Request Time Out when creating resources with REST

Tags: spring, rest, request, tomcat7, request-timed-out

We have a `REST` based server and the issue is that some resources take long time to create - take couple of minutes<10m.

**The problem:** is that by the time the resource is created I am getting request timeout error on the client instead getting the resource back.

I thought of couple of possibilities

- Create the resource with the `POST` request and add it to the session/db and then send a GET request to get the resource back. I dont like this solution: it is not "REST", and I will have to send couple of get requests that will return 404 until the resource is fully created
- Set my server (Tomcat 7 & Spring 3.2) with a longer session time out
  duration - I dont really know how to do it.
- Is there a way for the server to send a response to client saying "Hold it" until he returns the final answer? - Dont really know how to do that
- Is there a way to send a request that simply "waits" longer to the server to respond?
  Dont really know how to do that

What is the best practice around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: We can increase the value please refer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout

Comment: @Kumar Which one? I tried the accepted answer and the answer below it but it didnt work.

Comment: @specialOne Please post the server error log. Is it session timeout / Request timeout / Database transaction time out?. The solution in the above link will work for Server request timeout problem.

Comment: @Kumar It is because I am using Openshift. They put haproxy on the front with out any ability to configure. Which throws the exception. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it will take a long time to create the resource tell it immediately to the client. Don't block him for minutes.

A common way is to answer with the status code `202 (Accepted)`. Add a `Location` header with a URI that points to a second resource the client can poll to get more information about the current status.

This second resource should answer with a `200 (OK)` and the current status ("still pending, please try again in 30 seconds"). If the creation of the first resource is finished the second one should answer with a `303 (See Other)` and the URI of the first resource in the `Location` header.