# What are the Tomcat Equivalent to these WebLogic settings

Tags: tomcat, weblogic

Can someone please tell me what the Tomcat equivalents are to these WebLogic settings:

- Connect Timeout
- Results Time Limit
- Keep Alive Enabled

Comment: There are not enough details here. Weblogic has many timeout settings. Post timeout? Http message timeout? Idle connection timeout? Results time limit for what? For jdbc? For post requests? Keep alive is under http post settings for your server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about HTTP requests and not JDBC connections, in general these are settings in a Tomcat connector, configurable in server.xml:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

The specific values you are looking for are:

```
connectionTimeout
socket.soKeepAlive
```

Results time limit is trickier. You will need a valve to do this. See:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve

[Tomcat request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout)

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Valve 
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve"
    threshold="60" />
  ...
</Context>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try this, and if this results in the Behavior I want, I will select your answer.