# Spring MVC controller set time limit

Tags: spring-mvc, time-limiting

I am launching a long process in al web request in Spring MVC and I would like to terminate it if the thread takes a long time. Are there anyway to set a maximum time to kill the thread in a Spring controller if it is too long? Is this the best approach or are there any other better way to do it? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout) that the thread can not be killed by the app-server without the colaboration of the thread.

I found Guava [TimeLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) but not sure how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: You use it like described. `TimeLimiter` essentially does what should (or rather has to) be done anyway: Run a task asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it with a Timelimiter:

```
        TimeLimiter limiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
        limiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws IOException {
                return mymethod ();
            }
          }, timelimit, TimeUnit.SECONDS, false);
```

If the method take more than time than the timelimit, with throw an `UncheckedTimeoutException` exception that must be managed.

Comment: shat about bean scope?? This will create a new thread and you probably will lost bean status