# Timeout last 10 min in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

I have deployed a webapp in Tomcat 7, and I'm not using Eclipse, but when I run application last 10 min appear a timeout exception, exactly: Read timed out.

I've tried to change:

In `web.xml`:

```
session-timeout 30
```

In `server.xml` I added:

```
connectionTimeout="20000"
keepAliveTimeout="90"
```

Also I addes in `startup.bin` before `@echo off`:

```
CATALINA_OPTS=
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=900000;
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=900000
```

I don't know what other parameter to configure, because always stop to 10 min.

Someone can I help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse. Then goto server explorer and double click on your tomcat server.
It'll open a new tab inside your eclipse. There is Timeout section on the right side.
you can increase your session timeout time of tomcat server. without changing the server.xml

if it doesn't work follow below link

[Tomcat request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout)

Comment: Hi, I'dont use eclipse, I've installed a tomcat 7

Comment: Hi again, exactly what is file where I have that to write these line? Because I´ve tried into WEB-INF/web.xml

  <context-param>
  <Valve 
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve"
    threshold="60" />
  </context-param>

And into /conf/context.xml:
<Context>
   <Valve 
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve"
    threshold="60" />
</Context>