# In Tomcat7 or Tomcat8 what is the best method to limit a request timeout?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

The objective is simple. Limit how much time the request is ocuppying a Tomcat thread.

I've searched and found several "hacks" but I was expecting that Tomcat could give a similar setting like PHP `set_time_limit`.

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484800/2830850

Comment: Can you please check the below solution provided by me?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the **server.xml** file present under **config** folder of tomcat to set the connection timeout value.

Find the below line of code in **server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Edit the **connectionTimeout** attribute to the value you want. The value needs to be given in milliseconds.

This will set the connection timeout value for http connection.In case you want to do so for https (SSL) you have to set the attribute in below line of code in **server.xml** too

**Original**

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Modified**

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="30000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Reference is tomcat documentation

[Tomcat 7 Doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)