# Tomcat 8 SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, jersey, tomcat8

I have got this error in a HTTP request that returns more than 12MB of data, changing the connectionTimout on server.xml did not help (set to -1).

I have downloaded Tomcat source code but it is difficult to find exactly where from the timout configuration used to trigger this exception comes from.

Any ideas?

```
19-Sep-2022 13:56:03.667 SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-9] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
            at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1673)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:371)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:845)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:750)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:406)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:384)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
            at net.bull.javamelody.internal.web.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:88)
            at net.bull.javamelody.internal.web.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:81)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
            at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:262)
            at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
            at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2085)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeBytes(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1173)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:256)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:725)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:625)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ContentEncoder.aroundWriteTo(ContentEncoder.java:138)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
            ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:155)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:167)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1360)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:718)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:538)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:482)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:632)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:121)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:229)
            at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:614)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)
            ... 80 more
```

Comment: You may wanna take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout)