# Is there an equivalent of php max_execution_time in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat9

I have a request processing for way too long (I know!) that ends with **Internal Server Error** after exactly 60 seconds.

In Tomcat, is there a `max_execution_time` (like PHP) for aborting requests processing for too long?  Allowing request processing for 90 or 120 seconds would be very helpful.

Saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484800/1980659 but it only says that a thread will keep running on the server even if an error is returned to the client after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was Apache who was pulling the rug under Tomcat.  Just have to edit Apache `httpd.conf` and add a line :

```
TimeOut 180
```

Where 180 is the number of seconds allowed before Apache (and Tomcat) times out on long request processing.

See Apache Doc about [TimeOut](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout).