# How to read HttpServletRequest data with timeout?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, inputstream

When I receive an [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) I get [ServletInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream) and read the request body with `readLine` line by line. Now I wonder what if client is very slow and I want the `readLine` to return after a timeout.

I can probably schedule a `TimerTask` to interrupt the `readLine` and catch the `InterruptedException`. Does it make sense? Would you suggest another solution to read HTTP request body with timeout?

Comment: Good question. I've been facing this problem many times but do not yet have a good solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify Http Request timeout parameter on Java servlet container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414795/how-to-specify-http-request-timeout-parameter-on-java-servlet-container)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your own "tight" reading from the stream (small bufferSize value, eg. 8 bytes at a time) instead of readLine and assert your timeout within the iteration.
Other than that, you can't do much when you are blocking for IO (blocked in the in.read call in the example below).   When a thread is blocked on IO it won't react to interrupt.

```
long timeout = 30000l; //30s
int bufferSize = 8;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize);
try {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int byteCount = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        byteCount += bytesRead;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > start + timeout) {
            //timed out: get out or throw exception or ....
        }
    }
    out.flush();
    return byteCount;
} ... catch ... finally ....
```