# How to set timeout for a POST request using JSP / JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, post, timeout

I would like to know if there is some way to set the timeout for a POST request(I guess it is a POST request) from a JSP using JSF tags.

**I usually work with ExtJS and do this kinda stuff through AJAX(it's easy to configure the timeout) and don't know almost anything of JSF.**

Anyway I'm maintaining a legacy system and when the request is done the interface stops listening about 3 minutes after, I would like the interface to wait until there is a response of the server, it doesn't matter if it takes 10 or 15 minutes.

Here is the action method which I guess is a standard POST

```xhtml
<div style="position:absolute; top:-100">
    <h:commandLink action="#{ReporteSeguros.buscarRegistros}" id="buscarRegistros" target="fraGridPagos">
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:inputHidden id="sucursal" value="#{ReporteSeguros.sucursal}"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="region" value="#{ReporteSeguros.region}"/>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the buscarRegistros() method of the ReporteSeguros bean takes up to 15 min to complete??

Comment: Takes about 4 or 5 sometimes but as I said it's a legacy system, do you know something about the question?

Comment: The answer they gave you is correct. There's no way of managing the client side timeout. I would suggest you to deeply revise your strategy, maybe using a DB based handshake for task that has an unpredictably long duration. Making an user wait 4 or 5 minutes in front af a spinning browser is not acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kind of timeouts, one is **client specific** and the other is set by **the server**. You can configure the server one, properly configuring your application/servlet container. However, there's no way to control the client timeout which will be browser specific.

In short words, you'll need to change your control/persistence layer sooner or later in order to make the method perform faster.

**See also:**

- [How to specify Http Request timeout parameter on Java servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414795/how-to-specify-http-request-timeout-parameter-on-java-servlet-container)
- [Tomcat request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout)

Comment: The default keep alive timeout option can be changed in IE. Please, see link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Busted, sure you can. I meant there's no way to instruct your browser doing that, from the server. It would be a pain to tell all users to follow that instructions (or the ones relative to their browsers). Anyway, there are some clients you can control: mobile apps ;-)